# How to add background image to Button from material-ui in react?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to add background image to `Material-ui` button in `React` and I don't know how to do this correctly. Here is my code. Any ideas how to make it work? I was trying to add `backgroundImage` to styles, but that didn't work.

```
      const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
            buttonStep: {
                width: '150px',
                height: '49px',
                background: '#5F8FE8',
                backgrounImage: 'url("../../assets/icons/arrowButton.svg")',
              },
        }))
        export default function StepNavigation(props) {
        const classes = useStyles()

        return (

                   <Button
                        className={classes.buttonStep}
                    >
                        Next
                    </Button> 
         )}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem I see in your code is just a typo. You are missing the "d" in "backgroun**d**Image".

Here is a working example:

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  buttonStep: {
    width: "150px",
    height: "49px",
    backgroundImage: "linear-gradient(.25turn, #f00, #00f)"
  }
});

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <Button className={classes.buttonStep}>Next</Button>;
}
```

[image: Edit Background image Button]

Comment: You are right, another problem was that I didn't put current sizes for the svg, and I saw this button as a rectangle, even though svg had a different form!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure material ui supports background image for button or not. But you can use `IconButton` from material to use like arrow button

here is an example:

```
import React from 'react';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import NavigateNextIcon from '@material-ui/icons/NavigateNext';

export default function NextButton() {
    return (
        <div>
            <IconButton color="primary" aria-label="upload picture" component="span">
                <NavigateNextIcon/>
            </IconButton>
        </div>
    );
}
```